# Error with android sdk : Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies

Tags: android, flutter

I'm installing `Flutter` without installing `Android Studio` by following a [youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8v0Ifn4eOu4). and in there, first I install git then installed Flutter via, `Git` and then installed java and set up `JAVA_HOME` and other env variables. after that I installed `Android SDK Tools` and tried to run two of the commands:

```
[1] sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;28.0.3" --sdk_root=../

[2] sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-30" --sdk_root=../
```

The first command `sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;28.0.3" --sdk_root=../`  returns the following error:

```
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.
[===                                    ] 10% Computing updates...
```

but the second one runs fine.

So please help me resolve the error for command `[1]`!

Comment: I'm having the same error, however I'm running on arm64 and read that the build tools are not ready for arm64 yet. What machine are you running these commands on?

Answer (score 3):

You can try "build-tools;31.0.0" .
I did and it worked for me.