# Install build tools on arm64 doesn't work

Tags: android, arm64

I've been trying to install `sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.2"` on an arm64 processor (ampere CPU).

But every time I get this:

```
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!                         
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.
```

I'm trying to build an app and I get this error:

```
Failed to install the following SDK components:
      build-tools;30.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2
```

Edit: I think the problem is the package `emulator` isn't available. I tried [downloading it from here](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7176368/aarch64_sdk_tools_linux/latest/sdk-repo-linux_aarch64-emulator-7176368.zip) but sdkmanager didn't recognize it.

Comment: did you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/error-dependent-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk

Comment: Yes, But I'm not using the studio, Also, `./sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator` didn't work

Comment: have you installed necessary api level using sdk manager ?

Comment: Yeah, I already installed `platform-tools` & `platforms;android-29` but I can't install the build-tools

Comment: The problem is, I think, the emulator package isn't available for arm64. When I try `sdkmanager --list` and look for emulator, I can't find it.

Comment: @index9090 yes, I see the same thing.  I would like some confirmation on it.  Android command line tools for linux seem to only be available for amd64.  However, having said that I was able to install some other packages using sdkmanager.

Answer (score 2):

(Assumption: CMD Line Tools are installed)

SDK manager package "emulator" is missing on ARM

Workaround:

1. Download emulator from Google for Linux: https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive
2. Extract it to $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/emulator
3. You need a license file called "package.xml" which is automatically created when you download it via Android Studio UI SDK Manager, you copy that file to $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/emulator and change all version numbers related to the version you have downloaded:

   ```
   ... <revision><major>31</major><minor>1</minor><micro>4</micro></revision>...
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing this issue due to arm64 incompatibility, you can try doing exactly what I did.

1. First you'll need to update your android/build.gradle file

- Increase the buildToolsVersion to 32 or higher for example

```
   buildscript {
   ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"
   }
}
```

2. If you're using dependencies in your project that explicitly specify build tools version 30, gradle will still attempt to download it and that will cause an error.
   To prevent that, you can force all dependencies to use the buildToolsVersion of the main project. It might cause some issues, but if you are lucky, there will be none.
   This is how to implement that

```
buildscript {
   subprojects { subproject ->
      afterEvaluate{      if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin("android") || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin("android-library"))) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3. The binaries in the build and platform tools that sdkmanager will download are for x86_64 so the gradle build will still fail.
   To solve this problem, you'll need to either build those tools yourself or download them. After a long search I found these
   https://github.com/lzhiyong/android-sdk-tools/releases/download/33.0.3/android-sdk-tools-static-aarch64.zip
   All thanks to https://github.com/lzhiyong for building these tools and making them available.
   Other releases are here
   https://github.com/lzhiyong/android-sdk-tools/releases
   After downloading the tools, you should delete the binaries in your android sdk folder and symlink the paths to the downloaded binaries.

The binaries I symlinked in my case are,

**Build Tools**

aapt
aapt2
aidl
apksigner
zipalign
split-select
dexdump

**Platform Tools**

fastboot
adb
dmtracedump
e2fsdroid
etc1tool
hprof-conv
make_f2fs
make_f2fs_casefold
mke2fs
sload_f2fs
sqlite3

Most of them won't be used though, but just to be safe.

4. Gradle might still download the x86_64 aapt2 version and attempt to use it. To ensure that such doesn't happen,
   You can add this line to your android/gradle.properties file

```
android.aapt2FromMavenOverride=/path-to-downloaded-aapt2-binary
```

Good luck

Comment: For anybody who made the same mistake as me, this page is not for Apple Silicon and the resources will not work

Comment: lzhiyong's android-sdk-tools worked for me on Linux on aarch64 platform, and also on Android itself running on ARM64 devices (however I couldn't compile an app on an Android device )

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install build-tools using sdkmanager on arm64 by copying to the sdk dir emulator from
https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/refs/heads/main/sdk/emulator/

Unfortunately the installed packages seem to be not compiled for arm64 and are not working.